# Finding the symmetry point in a quadratic graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the symmetry point for a graph based on a quadratic equation?

Comment: If you're familiar with the quadratic formula, take the mean of the two roots of the quadratic equation and simplify the resulting expression.

Comment: If a quadratic function y = f(x) is meant, then J.M.'s suggestion is apt.  A general quadratic equation will have at least one line of symmetry.  Exactly one in the case of a parabola, even in general position, and exactly two in the case of a hyperbola.  An ellipse will have two lines of symmetry as well, with only a circle, two parallel lines, and two intersecting lines (the degenerate cases) exhibiting one or more point symmetries.

Comment: Note that the graph of a quadratic equation has a *line* of symmetry, not a *point* of symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

For an equation of the form $y= ax^2 + bx + c $ the axis of symmetry lies on the x-value $ \frac{-b}{2a}\ $.